# A word where when all factors occur, catastrophe happnes

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which describes/has the meaning 'all events/elements have to occur to have a catastrophe/catastrophic outcome'

Comment: You mean like "perfect storm"?

Comment: yes. like you need heavy rain, wind, etc to have a storm. If only one of the factors is present, like just rain, you wont have a storm @HotLicks

Comment: Yep, the usual term is "perfect storm".

Comment: @HotLicks is there a single word for it?

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: _Perfect storm_ may be two words, but it's an established phrase that can be regarded as a single lexeme. [A few dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=perfect+storm&ls=a) give the expression its own entry, and it means exactly what you want it to mean; Collins defines it as: _a combination of events which are not individually dangerous, but occurring together produce a disastrous outcome_

Comment: (*Not a single word*) "unhappy/wicked convergence of circumstances".

Comment: In the case of a manmade system, such as a nuclear power station or aeroplane, this concept is called redundancy. A triply-redundant system, for example, has three related components and if any two of them fail it is all ok but only if all three fail there will be a calamity. A doubly-redundant system is often called belt-and-braces in the UK (braces are called suspenders in US).. If the braces break the belt holds up the trousers, if the belt goes the braces hold up the trousers,. Only if both break will the catastrophe of the trousers falling down happen.

Comment: Could use _necessary_ or _required_.

Comment: I can see why people have proposed "perfect storm," but I don't think it answers the question.